# PHP's json_decode having problems with single but not double quotes

Tags: php, json

Easiest to explain via example:

```
var_dump(json_decode("[{'a':'b'},{'c':'d'},{'e':'f'}]")); // NULL
var_dump(json_decode('[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"},{"e":"f"}]')); // array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["a"]=> string(1) "b" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["c"]=> string(1) "d" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["e"]=> string(1) "f" } }
```

As you can see the first example where single quotes are used returns NULL meaning an error while the second one works fine.

Any idea as to why it is doing it or what I can do to help prevent problems other than doing a bunch of string manipulation?

Comment: read http://json.org/, use native json-encoding functions.

Comment: You can easily validate json using http://jsonlint.com/ or http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: `'` is not a valid quote in JSON. use `"` or go home, basically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A string in JSON is defined as:

```
""
" chars "
```

In other words, double quotes (not single) are necessary for JSON strings.  How are you getting this JSON?  We can look at a possible solution for validating/fixing the string before decoding.

Source: http://www.json.org/ and http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf

> A value can be a string in **double quotes**, or [...]

Comment: I would say that json.org is wrong... `'` is valid javascript and has no dynamic features...

Comment: actually JSON ⊊ Javascript.   Please note that JSON is an acronym for "Javascript" object notation.

Comment: @user3338098 wow I blanked on that one yesterday, thanks for correcting me. Still doesn't mean that the `'` is a valid string delimiter in JSON (I just read my answer and realizes that it doesn't specify that, I'll correct that).

Comment: @user3338098 do you not accept the JSON standards written by [Ecma International](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) or [IETF](http://rfc7159.net/rfc7159)? Which say *"A string is a sequence of Unicode code points wrapped with quotation marks ([U+0022](http://unicode-table.com/en/0022/))."* and *"A string begins and ends with quotation marks."* respectively.

Comment: Heck, try running `JSON.parse("{'foo':'bar'}");` instead of `JSON.parse('{"foo":"bar"}');` in your browser's console. You'll get a SyntaxError for an unexpected `'`.

Comment: I don't care about IETF or W3C or whoever else; I'm just saying, wrong is wrong (wrong or just incomplete).

Answer (score 1):

The first string isn't valid JSON. That's why [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) returns `NULL`. You can verify this using an online validator such as [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com).

According to the [specification in json.org](http://www.json.org/) (emphasis mine):

> A value can be a string in **double quotes**, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.

Fix your JSON. Use native encoding functions like [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) instead of hand-crafting it (if you're doing that). That way, you can be sure that the resultant JSON string is valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
$siteParameters = str_replace('\'','"',$siteParameters);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer will be much more useful if you include an explanation of how it answers the question.